# Não estou conseguindo alterar o conteúdo do meu botão

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando alterar o texto do meu botão quando eu clico nele, porém não estou conseguindo.

Meu código:

```js
function altera(argument) {
    document.getElementById('novo').innerHTML="atualizou"; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>noono</title>
  <script src="intercao.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button id="novo" onclick="altera()">Isso e um teste</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a propriedade `textContent` para isso:

```js
function altera(argument) {
  document.getElementById('novo').textContent ="atualizou";    
}
```

```html
 <button id="novo" onclick="altera()">Isso e um teste</button>
```

O `innerHTML` é usando para incluir conteúdo `html` com tags, no seu caso é apenas o texto dentro de um botão, então pode usar `textContent`.

A propriedade `innerText` tem a mesma função "semântica", ou seja alterar o texto e não conteúdo `html`. Embora ela não seja padrão, é utilizada no **Internet Explorer**, então se tiver problemas pode verificar qual usar.